# Regex string match for swift function call

Tags: objective-c, regex, swift, pattern-matching, function-call

What I need is to return whole line that contains the word 'func' and ends with '{'

I want to detect function declaration in a swift file and add a comment as first line of the function body.

For example:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^(-[^{]+\\{)" options:NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines error:&error];
```

This returns me every objective C function declaration in any .m file. **I just want the pattern that will replace ^(-[^{]+\{)**. So that I can apply for .swift file to detect swift function call.

The program is written in Objective-C so if anyone can give me Objective C pattern that returns line containing 'func' and ends with '{' - that will meet my requirement.

Comment: What have you tried? The difference between your old and new requirements seem rather minimal.

Answer (score -1):

I thnk this will search ur exact pattern u r looking.I've added to search one more word after func .So it will find a function declared like this

> func add {

**\b(w{4})\s(\w+\s[{])**

Comment: Your pattern does not match a literal `func`. Would this not make it too general?